# ng-model get access to nested objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a grid on my page, by click on row in this grid, User can see the form for editing values of this row. The problem is that I'm using ng-repeat that to show data and nested values displayed as [Object object]. How to get an access to this values? I've tried something like `rowData[k].name` but it returns only second part of form, the first part is empty. Where is my mistake?
[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q3afjheQXSd11XpnD7G2?p=preview)

Code:

```
$scope.load = function(){

  $http({
       method: "GET",
       url: 'test.json'
       })
       .then(function success(response) {
              $scope.rowData = response.data;
                  console.log($scope.rowData)
       }, function error(response) {
                 console.log("It has happend error in response")
  }).then(function(){
      $scope.id = $scope.rowData.id;
            console.log($scope.id);
           $scope.rowKeys = Object.keys($scope.rowData);
  })
  }
```

html:

```
<form style="padding: 15px" ng-submit="submitForm()" >
         <div class="form-group row">
          <div ng-repeat="k in rowKeys | filter: '!0' | filter: '!$$'" ng-model="rowVal" >
            <div ng-if="(k === 'id' || k.toLowerCase().endsWith('id') === false) ? true : false">
             <label for="rowValue" class="col-sm-2">
                {{k | hide:'.name' | makeUppercase }}:
            </label>
         <div class=" col-sm-2" >
              <input class="form-control rowValue" id="rowValue"
                       ng-model="rowData[k]"/>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData" ng-click="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your plunker/example, you are showing three types: object, string and number. You can use the `angular.isObject(value)` method to check if a value is object or not. If it's an object, you can use the dot notation. Otherwise just show the value.

```
<input ng-if="!isObject(rowData[k])" class="form-control rowValue" id="rowValue"
       ng-model="rowData[k]"/>

<input ng-if="isObject(rowData[k])" class="form-control rowValue" id="rowValue"
       ng-model="rowData[k].name"/>
```

```
$scope.isObject = function(value) {
    if(angular.isObject(value)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

See this [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ywdyw7XzOYal6sX3Jj9o?p=preview).

Comment: yeah it's working and doesn't return any errors in console, but what about  <label for="rowValue" has assigned to 2 ids, is it good?

Comment: Didn't get your question completely. By 2 ids if you meant two input boxes id for the same `label`, then the answer is only one of the input element will get created in the DOM and the other one will be removed from DOM. So, there is only one id(input box) at a time for a label.

Comment: I updated the plunker with some other modifications i.e made `label for` value to point to the input box id, removed `ng-model` from the `ng-repeat` div. If you click on a label, the cursor will point to the input box now. And there is no meaning to put `ng-model` in a div, so removed it.

Answer (score 1):

When working with objects you have two ways to access properties which are [Bracket Notation and Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). Dot Notation is the most common way to access properties of the object.

```
var myObject = {
  name: 'Anton'
};

//Bracket Notation
console.log(myObject['name']);

//Dot Notation
console.log(myObject.name);
```

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem, I need to display both ways of getting data as `rowData[k]` and this `rowData[k].name`. Currently I can display only one of this way

Comment: Even if it doesnt solve your problem, it will benefit you to learn the syntax.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you.

https://plnkr.co/edit/p5ghWAdIxXCQHYPhjzFU?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="load()">Push me</button>
      <form style="padding: 15px" ng-submit="submitForm()" >
         <div class="form-group row">
          <div ng-repeat="k in rowKeys | filter: '!0' | filter: '!$$'" ng-model="rowVal" >
            <div ng-if="(k === 'id' || k.toLowerCase().endsWith('id') === false) ? true : false">
             <label for="rowValue" class="col-sm-2">
                {{k | hide:'.name' | makeUppercase }}:
            </label>
         <div class=" col-sm-2" >
              <input class="form-control rowValue" id="rowValue"
                       ng-model="(rowData[k].name === undefined)? rowData[k] : rowData[k].name"/>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData" ng-click="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeah it  show data but console log returns `[ngModel:nonassign] Expression '(rowData[k].name === undefined)? rowData[k] : rowData[k].name' is non-assignable.`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
<div class=" col-sm-2" >
             <input  class="form-control rowValue"
                       ng-model="rowData[k].name || rowData[k]" />
        </div>
```

Comment: I like your method, I've tried rowData[k].name && rowData[k] cause we have to display rowData[k].name and rowData[k] cause both of this values is true, but I didn't even think about this operator 'II'.

Comment: && operator doesn't help. Have you tried that? It won't display anything. I am trying to use casting operator for displaying content. When it couldn't find the object with name property, it would display the original property. Thats where || operator helps. If you are using && operator, this will return false in all cases. Isn't it?

Comment: I didn't finish my sentence, I've tried && operator but it didn't help me and returns false every time, you are absolutely right! thanks!

Comment: The problem of your method is `Expression 'rowData[k].name || rowData[k]' is non-assignable`

Answer (score 0):

I think `rowData[k].name` is what you're looking for.

Comment: now it is displaying only second part of form. How could I force it to display every value?

Comment: Use two `input`s with different bindings (`rowData[k].name` and `rowData[k]`) conditionally (`ng-if`). The safest way would be to have a condition by property name.